# Something strange happened when I operated DOM using js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, automation, puppeteer

Can you achieve that choosing a `size` using js in the page from walmart.com？
I have tried some times, but no effect.
like this one:

```
document.querySelector('.prod-ProductVariantType .chooser-option-current div').click();
document.querySelectorAll('.prod-ProductVariantType div.chooser-option-list div div')[1].click();
```

nothing happended after I executed the above code.
Page URL：https://www.walmart.com/ip/NEW-Laptop-Cart-Table-Desk-Height-Adjustable-Portable-with-Rolling-Wheels-SPTE/794250587

The case is just like I mentioned in title.

**Updated**: I made a mistake that it should be `size` instead of `color`, sorry 
 for that again.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Did you want a way to choose between different colours of an item on your shopping page?

Comment: I urgently need to write a book titled like this question.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just want to choose one color using js, but no effort，even though after the color list shown and then clicked the color item.But if I clicked the color item manually，it worked.It make me confused :(

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love your question title. It is almost - no it **is** poetry. And definitely the best part of your question.

Comment: @connexo anyway, sorry about that, I have updated the question.:)

Comment: Well, now that you have completely changed the question, my comment looks retarded. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange happens if you run this code (it will select other color option):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.walmart.com/ip/NEW-Laptop-Cart-Table-Desk-Height-Adjustable-Portable-with-Rolling-Wheels-SPTE/794250587');

    await page.click('.prod-ProductVariantSwatch > div > div:nth-child(1) > label > span');

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'image.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```